# Unable to install client-go credential (exec) plugin for kubelogin

Tags: kubernetes, debian, prometheus, grafana, kubectl

I'm attempting to install client-go credential (exec) plugin for kubelogin since it gives me this error after running 'kubectl get pods' error: The azure auth plugin has been removed.
Please use the https://github.com/Azure/kubelogin kubectl/client-go credential plugin instead.
See https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/access-authn-authz/authentication/#client-go-credential-plugins for further details

I tried referring to the github page: https://github.com/Azure/kubelogin#setup. However after I run 'brew install Azure/kubelogin/kubelogin', it begins to install, but gets stuck on this line: ==> Downloading https://ghcr.io/v2/homebrew/core/linux-headers/5.15/manifests/5.15.102

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/APvPK.png)